# Time Format not working in Laravel Query builder select

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have a query in Laravel query builder like this-

```
    $ownQas = DB::table('qas')
                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'qas.subscriber_id')
                ->select(
                            'qas.question as question',
                            'qas.created_at as question_datetime',
                            'users.name as question_name',
                            DB::raw('NOW() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(qas.created_at) as question_ask_before'),
                            'qas.answer as answer'
                        )
                ->where('qas.webinar_id', '=' , $webinar['id'])
                ->where('qas.subscriber_id', '=' , Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('qas.public', '=' , 0)
                ->get();
```

It is working.

But if I try to find timestamps as formatted like this-

```
DB::raw('TIME_FORMAT((NOW() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(qas.created_at)),"%H:%i") as question_ask_before')
```

I am getting error.

Any idea?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What error you get? Please be  specific

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned about the error.

I am using postgreSQL.

Here is the working code for me

```
DB::raw("(TO_CHAR(NOW() - (t1.create_date),'HH12:MI:SS')) as question_ask_before")
```

Hope this will help you.